# [Angular]: Custom header not sent/seen to web api

Tags: angular, http, httprequest

I'm currently working on a Angular 6 app with a asp.net web api back-end. I'm trying to send a **Login POST request** to my web api (see code below)

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('client_id', this.clientapphelper.getClientApp());

return this.client
    .post(
        this.apiurlhelper.GetApiUrl() + "token?",
        "grant_type=password&username=" + account.Username + "&password=" + account.Password,
        {headers: headers}
    );
```

Now when I click submit, it hits the server but I can't see the **client_id** header being sent. I tried this with a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms and it works. Any ideas?

I also tried using **HttpInterceptor** but still no luck.

Comment: Can you try removing the `headers:` part and just use `{ headers }` directly?

Comment: Are you able to see the other headers except `client_id` in network tab of developer tools?

Comment: @SourangshuSengupta no luck.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, I can. One thing I notice though is that when using HttpInterceptor, client_id (not the value itself) is assigned to Access-Control-Headers-Request or similar name (forgot what header was it).

Comment: I think the problem is with the `"token?",` part.. It is because of the comma after token. After the first comma, second argument to the `post` method takes the post `body`, but I think what you are trying to do here is send query params. I would suggest building the whole url first and holding it in a variable, then sending that along with the headers.

Comment: @SourangshuSengupta Well, the request works fine without the client_id header being sent and having the "token?".

Comment: Not sure if this the problem, Can you just try out `headers.append('client_id', (this.clientapphelper.getClientApp()).toString());`

Comment: Then can you try adding the headers in the constructor as opposed to appending? Or interchanging the positions of client_id and Content-Type?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Doesn't work.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've already tried doing `new HttpHeaders({'header': 'value', 'header': 'value'});` but doesn't work either.